# How to make the windows command prompt show the return value on a C++ executable?

Tags: c++, cmd

I was using Dev C++ for coding c++ (for competitive programming, been doing it for a couple of months) but after a while I decided to try to do it on VSCode (terrible idea btw). Everything ended up working however when executing a program on the command prompt via Dev C++ it showed both the execution time and the return value of the main function like this:

```
Process exited after 4.962 seconds with return value 0
```

The problem is, when executing a c++ .exe file by normal means, these things are not shown and I don't even know where it comes from. Is there a program or a command that makes these show on the command prompt?

Edit: That comment solved my problem
"Execution time is not tracked by Windows. echo %errorlevel% prints the exit code."

Comment: Execution time is not tracked by Windows. `echo %errorlevel%` prints the exit code.

Comment: Judging solely by the questions I see here VS Code does seem to be a terrible idea, for newbies at least.

Answer (score 0):

A very rough example of achieving the requirement:

```
#include <iostream>
// to count time elapsed from beginning to end of the program
#include <chrono>
// for atexit() function
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std::chrono;

// used globally, see the reason below of the answer
int i;

void onExit();

int main(void) {
    int input;

    // clock begins
    steady_clock::time_point begin = steady_clock::now();

    // --- SOME LONG PROGRAM ---
    std::cin >> input;

    // clock ends    
    steady_clock::time_point end = steady_clock::now();

    // calculating the difference
    long long diff = duration_cast<milliseconds>(end - begin).count();

    // displaying the time    
    std::cout << "Process exited in " << diff / 1000.00 << 's' << std::endl;

    // on exit of the program, this function will be executed
    atexit(&onExit);

    // supposing the return code is 5
    i = 5;

    return i;
}

// exit function to be executed before exit    
void onExit() {
    std::cout << "Exit code: " << i << std::endl;
}
```

---

This will output something like:

```
test     // --- INPUT
Process exited in 4.383s
Exit code: 5
```

---

Notice that we've used the variable `i` globally since `atexit()`'s passed function must be returning void (i.e. nothing), that's the reason of not passing the `i` in the user-defined function `onExit()` and nothing else.

The [definition](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atexit/) of `atexit()` is as follows:

```
extern "C++" int atexit (void (*func)(void)) noexcept;
```